# How to add tip to a span or div to make a chat bubble?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a tiny triangular tip to the bubble.

```js
$('.check').on('blur', function() {
  $(this).prev('div.tooltip-inner').remove();

  if (!isValidEmailAddress($(this).val())) {


    var position = $(this).position(),
      validationdiv = $('<div></div>')
      .addClass('tooltip-inner')
      .text('Invalid Email')
      .css({
        left: position.left,
        width: $(this).outerWidth()
      })
      .insertBefore($(this));
    validationdiv.css({
      top: position.top - validationdiv.height(),
      display: 'block'
    });
    $(this).focus();
  }

});



function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
  return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

```css
.tooltip-inner {
  opacity: 0.8;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 10%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: -6px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #FF3B3B;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: visible;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
span {
  position: relative;
}
span:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: “”;
  border-color: #eee transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -19px;
  left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" class="check" />
```

Comment: What is chat bubble?

Comment: No I mean like a tiny triangular tip  like we have in a chat bubble?

Comment: isnt that what your code is doing now?expand on explanation more

Comment: @Pekka http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Speech-Bubble-Style-Tooltip-Plugin-Bubble.jpg

Can you see a small projecting tip at the bottom of rectangle?

Comment: Are you asking for [this](http://cssarrowplease.com/)?

Comment: @divy3993 yes, but can you help me give this effect in my snippet?

Comment: @Arbaaz I see that you have used my code from your previous question, but you accepted another answer at that question. This is wrong.. because for sure the answer you accepted is not correct..

Comment: this describes how to add a triangular tip: http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-speech-bubbles/

Answer (score 0):

I use this one: cssarrowplease.com
Works really good.

```
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #88b7d5;
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-left-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-left-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-top: -36px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

JS:

```
$('.check').on('blur', function() {

  if (!isValidEmailAddress($(this).val())) {
      showTooltip($(this), 'Invalid Email');
  }

});

function showTooltip(obj, msg) {
  obj.prev('div.tooltip-inner').remove();
  var position = obj.position(),
      validationdiv = $('<div></div>')
      .addClass('tooltip-inner')
      .text(msg)
      .append($('<span></span>'))
      .css({
        left: position.left,
        width: obj.outerWidth()
      })
      .insertBefore(obj);
    validationdiv.css({
      top: position.top - validationdiv.height() - 5,
      display: 'block'
    }).find('span').css({
      left: validationdiv.width() / 2 - 4
    });
    obj.focus();
}

function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
  return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip-inner {
  opacity: 0.8;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 10%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: -6px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #FF3B3B;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: visible;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.tooltip-inner span {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    content: “”;
    border-color: #FF3B3B transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    width: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/svg28gew/1/)